# Create XML from Excel Table

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I need some help here, im new at this trying to create XML files from an excel table. I am having some dificulties trying to pass the values from the table do the final XML file.

My table is this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWGGU.png)

Code snippet:

```
Sub ParserXML()

...

Set wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Work_path & "xxxx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Row_count = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

For i = 2 To Row_count

    DIM_NAME = ws.Cells(2, 19).Value
    EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = ws.Cells(2, 20).Value
    EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = ws.Cells(2, 21).Value
    Value = ws.Cells(2, 22).Value
    XMLFile.Write ("<STRING_INDEX DIM_NAME= """ & DIM_NAME & """ EFFECTIVE_END_DATE= """ & EFFECTIVE_END_DATE & """  EFFECTIVE_START_DATE= """ & EFFECTIVE_START_DATE & """  VALUE=""" & Value & """/>" & vbNewLine)

Next


...


End Sub
```

For now im receiving the same number of lines on XML as the table has, but just with the values of the first row.

Can someone help please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its working now! :)

Here is the code:

```
Set wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Work_path & "\xxxxx.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Row_count = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

For i = 2 To Row_count

DIM_NAME = ws.Cells(i, 19).Value
EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = ws.Cells(i, 20).Value
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = ws.Cells(i, 21).Value
Value = ws.Cells(i, 22).Value
XMLFile.Write ("<STRING_INDEX DIM_NAME= """ & DIM_NAME & """ EFFECTIVE_END_DATE= """ & EFFECTIVE_END_DATE & """  EFFECTIVE_START_DATE= """ & EFFECTIVE_START_DATE & """  VALUE=""" & Value & """/>" & vbNewLine)
```

Thanks anyway!